# Replaced RAM, getting BSOD thread exception not handled/kernel security check failure

Tags: memory, bsod

I bought a new DDR 3 8GB 1333mhz DIMM(transcend ts1glk64v3h) to replace my old
DD3R 4GB  DIMM (Apacer AU04GFA33C9QBGC). Now I can't boot into Windows or even get into safe mode, it does post and shows the 8GB and its 1333MHZ speed. I get a thread exception not handled on the blue screen then it restarts itself.

[image: first exception]

I have tried to use the 4 and 8 GB together with the same issue. I tried to swap their position (slots/ channels ) - same issue. I tried the 8 GB alone in both slots - same issue. If I use only the original 4 GB then the system will boot. My motherboard model is gigabyte ga-h55m-d2h.

Can someone advise as to what the cause of this issue might be and if there are any fixes, perhaps a BIOS setting?

The RAM was brand new, still sealed in packaging.

Update: after letting it try to boot a few times it gave me this Kernel error:

[image: second exception]

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit Intel i5 (133x 24 = 3,192 Ghz)

Comment: Have tried restoring the default firmware settings?  Verify you don’t hardware reserved enabled.  Any error codes?  “Exception not handled” is a catch all type of error.

Comment: Hmmm what does that mean? Like resetting bios defaults?

Comment: Where do I find hardware reserved setting and error codes? It's a thread exception not handled so I'm assuming it's thread related but you'd probably know better

Comment: Screenshot of the BSOD might help.

Comment: Added a photo of the BSOD

Comment: @Reign Yes, reset the BIOS/UEFI settings to default.  Have you ran hardware diagnostics on the memory _(hardware diagnostics boot option is found in the BIOS/UEFI settings or from the boot menu)_.  The following Microsoft Docs links may provide helpful info: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7e--system-thread-exception-not-handled) and [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x139--kernel-security-check-failure)

Comment: So far I have tried to reset bios to default then optimal to no avail. I have since taken the ram to a friend and we tested it on his main board it worked fine .I also tried to run windows 7 via a flash drive with both 4 and 8GB dimms in and it won't boot . Now I have both the  4gb and the 8 GB dimms in and booted into Ubuntu via flash drive(using the try Ubuntu option ) and it's running and reading 11.7 GiB ram .

Comment: @Reign Are you using the correct RAM type for your system; if so, your last comment implies either a bad RAM module or a RAM header, or the RAM module's/RAM header's contacts are contaminated _(for the latter, use Isopropyl Alcohol with a concentration >90%; For the header, remove power from the MB first)_.  Please do what I suggested previously and run hardware diagnostics, which should be accessible either via the BIOS/UEFI settings Boot tab or via the BIOS/UEFI boot options that are accessed before it hands off to the OS' bootloader (on many systems, it's accessed via **`F12`**).